# Updating excel worksheet data with userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enter in information in a database that I have in excel using a userform. The catch here is that I need to be able to enter data into a specific cell using a text box. For example, I open the userform and in textbox1 I type 123 in textbox2 I type 321. When I hit the submit button in the userform the code should look for the text "123" in a specific column. If the text "123" exists in the column specified in the code then it should take the data entered in textbox2(321) and put it in a cell adjacent to the cell containing the text 123

I have combed the internet looking for a solution to this and only found one that only sort of worked.

This is the link to that solution:
https://youtu.be/cKKgYPfq3_I

The code wouldn't work consistently though. I don't know if this is because some of the edits I made to the code in this video caused the errors or if the code itself had any errors.

This will be for a database that will have a ton of information on it. Having a function like this would make it a lot easier for someone to update information on the database. You could have for example a list of phone numbers and names. With this function it would allow you to enter a name in one text box and a new phone number in the second text box. You could then update an individuals phone number when pushing the submit button.

Any suggestions would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance!

Below is what I have so far that I found from a different forum and edited from some help that I got from here. It doesn't seem to work. Then again it could be because the code wasn't at all intended for what I would like it to do. (My knowledge of VBA is limited to puzzle piecing code together that I can find that seems to work.)

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim datee As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



m = 1


If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then



On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

datee = TextBox2.Text


Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scrap")
lastrow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For r = 1 To lastrow


If WS.Cells(r, 2) = TextBox1.Text Then

    WS.Cells(r, 5).Value = TextBox2.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 8).Value = TextBox3.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 9).Value = TextBox4.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 10).Value = TextBox5.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 11).Value = TextBox6.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 12).Value = TextBox7.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 13).Value = TextBox8.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 14).Value = TextBox9.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 15).Value = TextBox10.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 16).Value = TextBox11.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 17).Value = TextBox12.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 18).Value = TextBox13.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 19).Value = TextBox14.Text


    Else

    WS.Cells(r, 2).Font.Color = vbRed

     m = 0


End If

Next
If m = 0 Then

MsgBox "Sales Order number not found,make sure the Sales Order Number you entered is correct", vbCritical

Else

MsgBox "Success", vbInformation

End If

TextBox1.Text = ""

TextBox2.Text = ""

TextBox3.Text = ""

TextBox4.Text = ""

TextBox5.Text = ""

TextBox6.Text = ""

TextBox7.Text = ""

TextBox8.Text = ""

TextBox9.Text = ""

TextBox10.Text = ""

TextBox11.Text = ""

TextBox12.Text = ""

TextBox13.Text = ""

TextBox14.Text = ""

Unload Me


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: MsgBox "Sorry an Error occured. " & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End If

MsgBox "Please Insert Data", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; Show us what you have tried! What was the one you found that 'sort of worked'? You should have a read of the [help] on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Ya thanks for that! I noticed that too but couldn't find the edit button.

Comment: @user3788685 So iv been working on this for a couple months now. Ive forgotten the source of the original solution. I'm not new to VBA, I can read the code mostly and puzzle piece code together to create programs that work for me but that doesn't mean that I always understand 100% what im looking at. The code that I have been using I found on a different forum and i'm not even sure I am reading it correctly. Ill post it momentarily

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46457618/edit)

Comment: All edits have been made. If anybody is still confused as to what I am trying to do please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks!

Comment: @user3788685 I went back and found the first solution that "Kind of" worked. I edited the question to post the link.

Comment: the code that you posted appears to be ok. what is the undesired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (we suppose that our sheet is the sheet2) :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim datee As Date


Application.ScreenUpdating = False





If IsDate(TextBox2.Text) Then



On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

datee = TextBox2.Text


Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
lastrow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For r = 2 To lastrow


If WS.Cells(r, 3) = TextBox1.Text And WS.Cells(r, 2) = datee Then

    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = TextBox2.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 5).Value = TextBox3.Text
    WS.Cells(r, 2).Font.Color = vbRed
    WS.Cells(r, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Font.Color = vbRed
    WS.Cells(r, 5).Font.Color = vbRed

    MsgBox "Success", vbInformation


TextBox1.Text = ""

TextBox2.Text = ""

TextBox3.Text = ""

Unload Me


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

End If

Next



MsgBox "Data not Found!!", vbCritical




TextBox1.Text = ""

TextBox2.Text = ""

TextBox3.Text = ""

Unload Me


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: MsgBox "Sorry an Error occured. " & vbCrLf & Err.Description

Exit Sub

End If

MsgBox "Please Insert Date in the Date Box", vbCritical

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect. If somebody was getting ready to update some of the data in the worksheet and opened the userform and accidently made a typo in textbox1 or textbox2 would it be possible to have a message box pop up that says something like "data not found" so the user would know that the data he intended to update was not updated properly? Right now if you make a typo the userform just closes and there is no way to know if what you intended to update was updated properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! The program works except that every time I execute the program I get the message "In some Cases Data not Found!!,Check the Dates with Red Font"  regardless of whether or not the information in textbox1 and textbox2 is correct.

Comment: Iv updated the code in the question. I made the changes you suggested but also added a few things so it would properly fit my needs. Namely:

Comment: I changed "Dim datee As Date" to "Dim datee As Integer", changed "If IsDate(TextBox2.Text)" to "If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text)", deleted the "And WS.Cells(r, 2) = datee" in "If WS.Cells(r, 3) = TextBox1.Text And WS.Cells(r, 2) = datee Then" added more text box references and changed the wording in the messages code. Take a look at what iv'e got so far. Maybe there is an error in what i tried to adjust. Thanks again!

Comment: In 1 hour I will be in the office and I will update the code

Comment: The code has been fixed..please check...if its ok...please accept my answer

Comment: I have a meeting that I need to go to so will not be able to check this until the second half of my day. I will get back to you as soon as I can if this works or not. If I can get this to work you bet I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ok no problem!!

Comment: I was able to take a look at the code. It looks like you changed r =2 to r=1. Im not sure why but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to want to follow the "If WS.Cells(r, 2) = TextBox1.Text Then" command. It seems that even if this command is true it still thinks it's false and executes the "Else" command and as a result displays the msgbox saying "Sales Order Number not found." . Any Idea on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Everything works flawlessly.How to I accepts your answer here so I can help you out with your score?

Comment: on the left on zero click the up arrow

Comment: I hit the up arrow and nothing happens. Is there a way I can chat you? This thread is getting a little long. Im curious to know if you offer consulting services but would prefer to not talk about it on a public thread.

Comment: Awesome. is there a way to chat with you instead of on this thread? I am wondering if you would be willing to quote me on a project I would like to get started.